# Проверка checkbox и вывод соответствующего css-файла на сайте

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование

Как на сайте можно реализовать переключение тем оформления?

В общем, столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой, которая заключается в выводе определённой цветовой палитры на сайте (то бишь ночной режим) при установлении галочки. Как я понимаю, я могу создать функцию на php, которая будет проверять, установлена ли галочки или нет, а после- вывести на экран нужный css файл. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, так как не понимаю до конца, как сделать такую функцию. Может быть, это дело можно провернуть на js, но всё же, я не знаю(

Comment: тут помогают с решением проблемы а не решают ее

Answer (score 0):

Впервые делаю такое, основываясь на простых знаниях JavaScript-а. Реализовал с помощью библиотеки jQuery, но так же можно было реализовать с помощью ванильной JS. Просто при событии click нужно изменить ссылку на css файл в head. Например, можно задать тегу **link** атрибут **id** и с помощью JS обратиться к нему.

Кусок кода для примера(полный код не стану ставить, я должен помочь а не реализовать вместо вас, это в вашу же пользу):

В `head`:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" id="color-style" href="red.css">
```

В `body`:

```
<button class="red-btn btn">Change BG to red</button>
<button class="blue-btn btn">Change BG to blue</button>
```

И собственно `JS`:

```
$(".red-btn").click(function () {
   $("#color-style").attr("href", "red.css");
});
$(".blue-btn").click(function () {
   $("#color-style").attr("href", "blue.css");
});
```